# React Redux .map items, and in <child componenet> fetch data to display for each item

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have `Component` with **clients list** > **for each client** I'm adding a `Child Component` with list of the **client's orders**.

from the `Child Component` I'm calling `fetchClientOrders` (for the orders list), and getting it to props in the `Parent Component`- when I tried to `setClientOrders` in the `Child Component`, I got an error `"Uncaught TypeError: clientOrders.map is not a function"`

What is the right way to fetch data for each child component and display it with React Redux?

Thank you!

**Parent Component - clients list**

```
{clients.map((clientDetails, index) => {
                return  (
                        <Card key={index}>
                            <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey={clientDetails.id}>
                                <Row style={{textAlign:'center'}}>
                                    <Col style={{margin: 'auto'}} xs lg="1">{clientDetails.id}</Col>
                                    <Col style={{margin: 'auto'}}>{clientDetails.first_name} {clientDetails.last_name}</Col>
                                    <Col style={{margin: 'auto'}}>{clientDetails.client_type}</Col>
                            </Accordion.Toggle>
                            <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={clientDetails.id}>
                                <Card.Body>
            >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>           <ClientOrdersList clientId={clientDetails.id} />
                                </Card.Body>
                            </Accordion.Collapse>
```

**Child Component - Client's Orders**

```
function ClientOrdersList(props) {
    const [clientOrders, setClientOrders] = useState([])
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(props.fetchClientOrders(props.clientId))
    }, [props.clientId]);

    return (
        <div>
                <Table striped bordered hover size="sm">
                    <thead>
                    <tr style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                        <th>........
```

**Action - fetchClientOrders**

```
export const fetchClientOrders = (clientId) => {
    return async dispatch =>{
        dispatch(fetchingRequest())
        try {
            let response = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/orders/?client_id=' + clientId)
            dispatch({
                type: 'FETCHING_CLIENT_ORDERS_SUCCESS',
                payload: await response.data
            })
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error)
            dispatch(fetchingFailure(error))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ciao, can you show me on code where you use `setClientOrders` ?

Comment: in the useEffect of the child component, I'm just replacing to: `setClientOrders(dispatch(props.fetchClientOrders(props.clientId)))`

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, your error means that `clientOrders` is not an array (on which you can call `.map` function). This happend because, when you set `clientOrders` you write

```
setClientOrders(dispatch(props.fetchClientOrders(props.clientId)))
```

dispatch function does not returns data you want. If you want to retrieve your data from redux store you have to do something like:

```
import { useSelector} from 'react-redux';
...
function ClientOrdersList(props) {
...
const data_you_stored_in_redux = useSelector(state => state.YourReducer.data_you_stored_in_redux); // this line out of useEffect
...
}
```

`YourReducer` is the name of reducer that contains `data_you_stored_in_redux` that you passed in redux store like:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";
import YourReducer from '../../components/YourComponent/YourReducer';
...

const reducers = combineReducers({
   YourReducer,
   ... //other reducers
});

const store = createStore(reducers);
```

Comment: `const orders = useSelector(state => state.clients.clientOrders)`  return Undefined first - so I tried `useSelector(state => state.clients.clientOrders ? state.clients.clientOrders : [])`   ---- it returns for all the clients the same orders (the final request), how can I set it?  what am I missing? ,  Thank you!

Comment: ** I can't use `useSelector` from inside `useEffect` so how can I setClientOrders for the right client?

Comment: Ciao, `state.clients.clientOrders` your reducer file is called clients? Then, is not necessary to put `useSelector` inside `useEffect`. On component, just write `const orders = useSelector(state => state.<NameOfReducer>.clientOrders)`. I try to update my answer with a better explanation.

Comment: For: `const clientOrders = useSelector(state => state.clients.clientOrders)`  I'm getting > `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: And for: `const clientOrders = useSelector(state => state.clients.clientOrders ? state.clients.clientOrders : [])`  I'm getting > for each client in the list the orders of the last client it fetched

Comment: I think that `clients` is not your reducer name. Because on question you wrote `{clients.map((clientDetails, index)...`

Comment: it's because in the `Parent Component` I set `const clients = useSelector(state => state.clients.clients)` so I'm mapping that.  and getting the clients to show, so both my reducer and my object in .map called `clients`

Comment: Of course if you use `const clientOrders = useSelector(...)`, `const [clientOrders, setClientOrders] = useState([])` is no longer necessary and you can remove it.